# JavaScript RegEx group conglomeration

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to parse the following string format:

```
<id>:<name>[,<name>]*
```

As an example, consider `123:test,south-west,best,rest_well`.

I wrote the following regex:

```
/(\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(?:,([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+))*/
```

My assumption was that `(?:,([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+))` would capture optional additional names (south-west, best, and rest_well). However, it only captures the last name 'rest_well'.

The printed out match:

```
'123:test,south-west,best,rest_well'.match(/(\d+):([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)(?:,([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+))*/);
> ["123:test,south-west,best,rest_well", "123", "test", "rest_well"]
```

What I was expecting:

```
> ["123:test,south-west,best,rest_well", "123", "test", "south-west", "best", "rest_well"]
```

I believe other languages would actually accumulate the matched groups but somehow this fails. Maybe I am missing a small detail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yep, looks like it is. Too bad but I can write it differently. Just hoped for a pretty solution ;)

Comment: The easy solution would be to split on a delimiter. See [yate's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24332468/1438393).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to split the string with `:` or `,`.  Would this work?

```
var str = "123:test,south-west,best,rest_well";
var res = str.split(/:|,/);
```

Output

```
["123", "test", "south-west", "best", "rest_well"]
```

Comment: Hey, that's pretty sweet solution! I'd just add the following test to validate format:
   var re = new RegExp(/^\d+:[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+(?:,[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)*$/), 
      str = '123:test,south-west,best,rest_well', 
      res = null; 

   if (re.test(str)) {
      res = str.split(/:|,/)
   }
   else {
      res = [];
   }